# how to Handle ReadTimOut Exception while reading data from server?

Tags: java, android, exception

I am downloading long files from Amazon S3 server. I log excpetions to my server DB if any occure. What I see is large number of exceptions is **java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out**

I thought this is occur when user is in bad/poor internet coverage but I wonder if user is in bad coverage area then why that is logging on server?(As this also done via internet). Any body know reason?

The line at which this exception occurs every time is

> **while ((numRead = inputStream.read(mBuffer)) >= 0)**

How I can handle that exception? I am thinking that when exception occur then I should again make a try about no of time e.g 5 time by calling

> inputStream.read(mBuffer);
>
> Is I am thinking correct?
>
> Is after read time out exception occur the inputstream will be valid to use again?
>
> Will calling inputStream.read(mBuffer); will be resume from the last stream readed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input stream remains valid, and the buffer contains no data after a timeout. If you're getting lots of timeouts I would start by increasing the timeout period. Double it. And it should be at least 30-60 seconds to start with, as you want all the data.

Comment: Thanks for you time. Can you please tell me 1 more thing?
If exception occurred Will calling again inputStream.read(mBuffer); will be resume from the last stream readed?

Comment: @Arsian I've answered that. 'The buffer contains no data after a timeout.' Think about it. The timeout occurred instead of transferring any data into your buffer. So there wasn't any data, which is why it was reading, so there is nothing to get lost.

Comment: Oh yes , I was thinking in the same way. Thanks

Comment: If i download 1GB data then what i should do because i found then same issue